# user defined data type in set in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

In the first case, code is working fine but I am getting an error in the second code, the only difference is of "const" in the operator overloading of '<', I am not able to figure out why.
Code for both cases are below
1.

```
class first
{
    public:
    int y;
    bool operator < (first t) const
    {
        return (y>t.y);
    }
};
set<first> f;
```

2.

```
class first
{
    public:
    int y;
    bool operator < (first t) 
    {
        return (y>t.y);
    }
}; 
set<first> f;
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: passing 'const first' as 'this' argument of 'bool first::operator<(first)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: independend of your error, a non-const comparsion operator rarely makes sense. Just after you compared two isntances you still dont know which of them is bigger, because comparing them may have modified their internal state.

Comment: what do you mean by "may have modified their internal state" , how comparing two classes can change their internal state?

Comment: your `bool operator < (first t)` (note: no `const`) is allowed to modify the `y` member. It does not modify it, but from outside you cannot tell, so you have to assume `y` is different before and after comparing two instances

Comment: you could have eg `bool operator < (first t) { bool result = y > t.y; y = 10; return result; }`. Of course this doesnt make sense, but if you declare `operator<` as `const` then such non-sense cannot happen

Answer (score 4):

The default comparator for [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is `std::less<Key>` and as we can see on [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) it defines:

```
constexpr bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

Which accepts const arguments and returns `lhs < rhs`. This of course doesn't work if `lhs < rhs` is not valid for const arguments, as it is in your second case because `bool operator < (first t)` cannot be called.

---

Writing your own comparator which accepts non-const arguments doesn't seem to work either, so it looks it is a requirement of the ordered container, but further check with the standard is needed to confirm.

Comment: It is obviously a requirement. Imagine if comparison operator changed the data it compared? That would be just like quantum mechanics. Utter chaos! We still work with normal/classic computers not quantum computers.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set`, like most other containers in the standard library, uses the requirement [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for its comparing function. And the `Compare` requirement enforces constness:

> As with any BinaryPredicate, evaluation of that expression is not allowed to call non-const functions through the dereferenced iterators.